# VHDL - Subtype or type has null range

Tags: fpga, vhdl, quartus, intel-fpga

What is the meaning of the following warning (raised by Quartus)?

```
Warning (10445): VHDL Subtype or Type Declaration warning at someFile.vhd(32): subtype or type has null range
```

The offending line of code is:

```
-- Drive unused low
q( N - 1 downto X ) <= ( others => '0' );  -- drive unused low
```

`N` and `X` are integer constants used successfully elsewhere in the code (without raising warnings). `q` is declared as `q : out std_logic_vector( N - 1 downto 0 )`

The same error is also raised for this line of code (in another file):

```
-- Upper nibble
q <= zero( N - 1 downto 8 ) & q0( 7 downto 4 ) & zero( 3 downto 0 );
```

`N` is an integer constant used successfully elsewhere in the code. `q` is declared as `q : out std_logic_vector( N - 1 downto 0 )`. `q0` is declared as `signal q0 : std_logic_vector( N - 1 downto 0 )`. `zero` is declared as `constant zero : std_logic_vector( N - 1 downto 0 ) := ( others => '0' )`

It seems `( others => '0' )` is the common point for both, but I don't know how this relates to the null range warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range: `N - 1 downto X` is evaluating to a range with 0 or negative size.
Consider the range: `0 downto 4`, it has a size that is less than 0 since the number before the downto is less than the number after it.

The problem here is using a range that has a size less than 1 makes it a null range which has some valid uses in vhdl. However, since this is potentially a range error Quartus gives the warning you are seeing here.

Comment: Thank you! The code was initially written for 16+ bits (N=16). Using it for 8 bits (N=8) caused the subtle error. `N - 1 downto 8` became `7 downto 8`

Comment: VHDL allows you to have NULL ranges and NULL slices. That's why it is a warning and no error. There are good use cases using NULL ranges. But in most cases it's an error in the calculation of slice boundaries.